# Entries not appearing in phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, sql-insert

I have been trying different variations of this code for hours. I am a newbie. I cannot seem to figure out why nothing is getting inserted into the phpMyAdmin database. I have verified that I am connected to the database (using echo and error function below). I know mysql_ is in the process of being deprecated but please help a brotha out. My question again: Why is nothing getting inserted? I'm using PHP 4.0.10.7 (Godaddy).

```
<?php

$first_name = $_POST['first_name'];
$last_name = $_POST['last_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$password = $_POST['password'];
$phone_number = $_POST['phone_number'];


define('dbusername', 'someusername');
define('dbpassword', 'somepassword');
define('dbhost', 'localhost');
define('dbname', 'somedb');

if (($first_name=="")||($last_name=="")||($email=="")||($password=="")||($phone_number=="")) 
        { 
        echo "All fields are required, please fill <a href='home.html'>the form</a> again."; 
        die();
        } 

$connect = mysql_connect(dbhost,dbusername,dbpassword) or die("Could not connect. " . mysql_error());

$db = mysql_select_db(dbname, $connect);

$queryemail = "SELECT * FROM User WHERE email = '$email'";

$insertemail = "INSERT INTO User (email,password,first_name,last_name,phone_number) VALUES ('$email','$password','$first_name','$last_name','$phone_number')"; 

echo $insertemail;
mysql_close($connect);

header("Location: account_summary.html");

?>
```

Echoing $insertemail returns

> INSERT INTO User (email,password,first_name,last_name,phone_number) VALUES ('asdfsda@sdfa','','sadf','asdf',''). The password doesn't show up, but neither does the phone number. Actual Form I'm testing on is located at Desotocab.com. Thank you!

As requested:

```html
<form action="login.php" method="post">
  
  <label>First Name: *</label><input type="text" name="first_name"/><br/>
  <label>Last Name: *</label><input type="text" name="last_name"/><br/>
  <label>Email: *</label><input type="email" name="email"/><br/>
  <label>Password: *</label><input type="password" name="password"/><br/>
  <sub>Password must be 8 characters minimum</sub><br/>
  <label>Phone Number: *</label><input type="text" name="phone_number"/><br/>

  <input type="submit" value="Sign Up"/>

</form>
```

**User** Table Schema:

Column     |     Type
user_id    |     int(11)
email      |     varchar(22)
password    |    varchar(64)
created_on   |   timestamp
first_name   |   varchar(50)
last_name    |   varchar(50)
phone_number |  varchar(20)

Comment: post your form code too

Comment: Also please provide your table schema.

Comment: check your data you have getting with post or not..?
`echo "<pre>";print_r($_POST);echo "</pre>";`

Comment: `($password="")||($phone_number="")` You're assigning empty strings to these variables instead of checking equality. Use `==`, not `=`.

Comment: where is mysql_query?

Comment: Also, it seems like you're just learning(?). I'd suggest switching to hosting with PHP5.6+ as PHP4 is dead and gone, well gone. Also, once doing that, look at PDO and prepared statements.

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan could you explain why does mysql_query need to be present?

Comment: @JonStirling ah i see. i will update this code and move onto 5.6+ and PDO very, very soon. Oh, and I posted the table schema and fixed the assignment errors!

Comment: @JonStirling the assignment errors were causing the password and phone number to not show up, so that problem got fixed too!

Comment: @GovindRai Good to hear :)

Comment: @SugumarVenkatesan my question got answered below in Bhanu's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change above code from MySQL compatible to MySQLi compatible 
 
 
then
Use

```
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $insertemail);
```

before

```
echo $insertemail;
```

Comment: to use MySQL*i* the whole code will need to be changed to MySQLi, this is ***highly encouraged***, but will explain why coping the above code line will simply cause you another error. There are lots of guides about how to swap from MySQL to MySQLi on the interwebs, it's pretty straight forward

Comment: I have been using mqsql instead of mysqli. Is it okay to use both or should I stick with mqsqli? Also could you explain why I need to use mysqli_query function at all? Wouldn't `$insertemail = "INSERT INTO User (email,password,first_name,last_name,phone_number) VALUES ('$email','$password','$first_name','$last_name','$phone_number')"; 
` already send the sql query to the database?

Comment: @GovindRai No, without using a query / execute method / function nothing will be sent to the database. What you've just commented is just a string in a variable that happens to resemble SQL. For PHP a string is a string, nothing more.

Comment: @JonStirling you're absolutely correct. this solved the problem! Is there a specific button you can click to show the question has been answered?

Comment: @GovindRai What you can do is accept an answer, or just leave it. Which option you take is entirely up to you depending on whether you feel an answer helped you fix your problem.

Comment: @JonStirling One last question for you, please! I have made revisions to my code and made it more appropriate using `if` statements, etc., I want to put my code up so that others can reference it to use on their own. Is there a way to add my "final" code to this question? Just for reference purposes.

Comment: Sure. I think you should still be able to edit your question so just add an update to the end.